# Why doesn't javaScript allow the use of double comparison?

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

Why doesn't javaScript allow the use of double comparison? For instance, in `64 < str.charCodeAt(i) && str.charCodeAt(i)<=77`, why can't I just say `64 < str.charCodeAt(i)<=77` for simplicity.

Comment: The answer may be simply "Because the language specification doesn't support that". Are you asking the philosophical question "Why have the designers of the language not included this functionality in the specification"?

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it won't do what you think it will.

```
64 < str.charCodeAt(i)<=77
```

is parsed as

```
(64 < str.charCodeAt(i)) <= 77
```

So it'll perform the `<` comparison, getting a boolean result. Then it'll convert that boolean to a number (zero or 1) and perform the `<=` test.

As to the question of *why* it's like that, it's most likely that the conventions of the C language family (already 20 years old when JavaScript was designed) seemed appropriate and familiar to lots of programmers. C works the same way. Java doesn't because it's got a real Boolean type and it doesn't like most implicit type conversions, so the whole thing would look like a syntax error in that context.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax works but does not do what you are expecting.

True == 1 and False == 0 are both true. So `true > x` is true where x is any number smaller than 1, and `false > x` is true where x is any number smaller than 0.

So a "double comparison" like:

`1 < 2 < 3`

evaluates to:

`true < 3`

which is roughly equivalent to:

`1 < 3`

which is true in this case.